# Access D-link webcams on Ubuntu

Tags: digital-cameras

I am the system administrator for some friends who have a couple of web-cams for professional surveillance at a small commercial plant.  The cameras are D-Links from the DCS series.

Currently, they are accessing them through the Mydlink portal.  This works fine *(tm)* most of the time, unless you try to access them from a Ubuntu system.  Then mydlink.com gives this error:

> #### Unsupported Browser or Operating System Detected!
>
> You are using an unsupported browser or operating system and therefore the mydlink web portal may not look, behave or function as intended.

Looking at the list of available options, it appears that the only operating systems that are supported are Mac and Windows.  Is there a way to access the cameras from Ubuntu short of setting up a custom web page with dynamic DDNS?

Comment: Same here on Windows, it forces me to use IE or Firefox. I thought this error was only browser dependent... Good to know

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<sub>N.B.: Including this answer here in hopes that it helps someone else.</sub>

### Yes, it's actually quite simple.

The issue is not so much with the operating system as it is that mydlink.com has not officially supported the Ubuntu operating system.  Therefore, all that is necessary is to fake your user agent.  There are several options on how to do this:

#### 1. Directly from the Chrome console

Simply follow these steps:

- Press F12.
- Click on the Console Tab
- Click on the Hamburger Menu > `More Tools` > `Network Conditions`
- Uncheck `Select Automatically`
- Select `Chrome -- Windows` or `Chrome -- Mac`
- Refresh the page.

#### 2. Install an extension

There are several extensions available for Chrome that will do this for you.  Some notable ones are [User-Agent Switcher for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg), [User-Agent Switcher for Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-g/ffhkkpnppgnfaobgihpdblnhmmbodake?hl=en), and [User-Agent Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher/dbclpoekepcmadpkeaelmhiheolhjflj?hl=en).

Comment: In my case the `Firefox - Windows` option, not the other two worked. Great solution!

Comment: D-Link DCS-932L, where the L might stand for deLuxe, but I had to select IE-11. Besides, the three dots menu icon in Chrome is called "ellipsis", or, for the rest of us, the kebab icon :-)